# Stuck on react routing from side bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new to react and working on react-routing and i am stuck. I created a component and added a   Link to = "/" which is working fine when this component is rendered. but the same link is not working in the sidebar component. It only changes the route but dont render the home component.

Any help will be appreciated.

so for example,

my app.js file consists of routes such as this

Route   path="/home" component={Home}/>

which is rendered fine when i am calling home component from any other component via link to="/home" but when i am using the same link to="/home" from sidebar component. it just changes the routes and doesn't render the home component.

my sidebar component is just like any other component.

i am not sure why it is happening.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? How is your router configured ? How is you Home component linked to sidebar?

Comment: yes i have added a bit more explanation, please see

Answer (score 0):

React Router provides a `<Switch>` component which is useful when you have multiple routes.

You can wrap your `<Route>`s in a `<Switch>` inside the router.

A simple example is:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={() => "Home"} />
    <Route path="/messages" component={() => "Messages"} />
    <Route path="/another" component={() => "Another"} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Reference article: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch